# How do I import a Chrome app I made into Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I've made a simple Chrome app that will redirect the user to my website when they run it, but I can't figure out how to put in Chrome. How exactly would I do this?

**Note:** I only have manifest.json and icon.png files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to install it on your Chrome? If so;

1. Go to settings/extensions by clicking the menu icon on the top right.
2. Click on "Load unpacked extension" on the top left of the extensions page.
3. Select your folder and it should be done.

(Edit: developer mode needs to be on)